# How to get xml nodes count in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl

**I want to get the count of xml nodes present in the file with specific tags in camel exchange or camel route.**

My xml tags are like this:

```
<parent>
  <child>
    <data>A</data>
  </child>
  <child>
    <data>B</data>
  </child>
  <child>
    <data>C</data>
    <child>
       <data>C1</data>
    </child>
    <child>
       <data>C2</data>
    </child>
  </child>
</parent>
```

I want to count the `<child>` tags and it should return 5 for this.

Currently, I am getting size using Exchange but it is giving output as 3.

```
exchange.getIn().getBody(XmlTreesType.class).getParentTree().getChildNode().size();
```

Comment: You can also count the number `<child>` text's in the xml as a string value. Or try to use xpath and a count function

Comment: Hi claus,  I am very much fresher in camel and not sure about many things. Help me out with a bit of example to get the count. Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This highly depends on your actual use case.

To extract the count, you could use the [XPath language](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/xpath-language.html) which allows you to extract information from XML easily.

To extract the count of all `<child>` nodes within your `<parent>` you could use the following:

```
count(/parent//child)
```

XPath expression.

To extract this value and store it in a header variable would look like this:

```
.from()
  .setHeader("childCountHeader", xpath("count(/parent//child)", Integer.class));
```

Another typical use case in the camel Java DSL would be along the following, in order to directly route based on the count:

```
from()
  .choice().xpath("count(/parent//child)>5")
  //do something
  .otherwise()
  //do something else
  .end();
```

If you want to use XPath inside vanilla java, as in a camel processor. You can build up an XPath processor as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2811101/3346612).